# jQuery - why $(this) doen't work in child scopes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, callback

I can't figure out why this script won't work unless i create a reference to $(this) and assign it to another variable like $_this = $(this); this was the only solution i got, but was wondering if there is a better one - a less newbie one. Observe that i want to be able to use it in the $_this.prepend("Choose"+res) part, after the get response in a callback function:

```
 $('#loadScript').one('click',function(e){
    $loading = $('<span> Loading Files... </span>');
    $(this).after($loading);
    $_this = $(this);

    $.get('eval.php',{loadScriptGetOptions:1}, function(res){
     setTimeout(function(){
      $loading.remove();
      $_this.prepend("<option>Choose</option>"+res);
     },1200)

    })

})
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use $ in front of loading? Why not use var loading...

Comment: I agree with JoshN. $ in from of the variable is PHP, not javascript.

Comment: cause i come from php. And besides i tend to create $vars when it holds jQuery objects, it makes sense to me. is it a real problem?

Comment: I like using $ when holding a jquery object too.  Just a naming convention to help me identify stored jquery objects easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $_this.prepend is getting called in a setTimeout function, where this is different then in the outer functions. You could have done something like:

```
function myFunc() {
    // What is $(this) here? 
}

 $('#loadScript').one('click',function(e){
    $loading = $('<span> Loading Files... </span>');
    $(this).after($loading);
    $_this = $(this);

    $.get('eval.php',{loadScriptGetOptions:1}, function(res){
       setTimeout(myFunc, 1200);
    })
})
```

Otherwise, I think your solution seems OK.

Note that `$_this` is a closure variable as used by function you use in `setTimeout`, so if you need to reference a known element, you can and **should** get rid of it as others commented (i.e. use `$('#loadScript')` to access the element directly).

Comment: hmmm, that makes sense, of course setTimeout is not anonymous, of course... thnks ;)

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the use of `var` in **two places**:

```
$loading = ...
```

and

```
$_this = ...
```

And I like `self` vs the ugly underscore there.

```
 $('#loadScript').one('click',function(e){

    var $loading = $('<span> Loading Files... </span>');
    $(this).after($loading);

    var $self = $(this);

    $.get('eval.php',{loadScriptGetOptions:1}, function(res){
      setTimeout(function(){
         $loading.remove();
         $self.prepend("<option>Choose</option>"+res);
      }, 1200);

    });

});
```

Comment: hmmm, you are right, thnks. So I should always use var when... i'm inside local scopes?

Comment: @Fablo Yes, otherwise it will be pushed to global scope.